# Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку

Tags: python, файлы, type-error

```
import pickle as pkl
import random

x1  = random.randint(1,1000)
y1 = (2*x1 - 93) / 12
x2 = random.randint(1,1000)
y2 = (x2 - 10 )/(x2 * 2) 
hm = open("hm.bin","wb")
hm.write(y1 + "\n" + y2)
pkl.dump((y1,y2),hm)
print(x1)
print(x2)
hm = open("hm.bin","rb")
x = pkl.load(hm)
hm_list = x.split("\n")
hm.close()
hm.close()
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'.
line 8, in <module>
hm.write(y1 + "\n" + y2)
```

Comment: побольше бы информации о том что у вас

Comment: Вот ошибка.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: `hm.write(y1 + "\n" + y2)` тут вы пытаетесь сложить число `y1` и строку `\n`

Comment: Ошибки не решают, решают задачи. Ошибки - исправляют.

Answer (score 1):

```
hm.write(y1 + "\n" + y2)
```

похоже тут ошибка

```
hm.write(f"{y1}\n{y2}")
```

или

```
hm.write(str(y1) + "\n" + str(y2))
```

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.